# integrating google calendar API to react hooks

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, reactjs

my question is how to integrate using react?
the calendar needs to create new appointments, manage or edit appointments,
sharing and inviting new bookings?

I have already tried getting a google api by fetching,
and installing packages but nothing is working.

Comment: Would you mind describing what exactly you have tried already, including screenshots and code excerpts?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using the package `react-big-calendar` and fetch events from Google Calendar API. It worked with me and I am using `create-react-app`. Check out the steps:

1. Install theses packages: `npm i react-big-calendar moment superagent style-loader css-loader`
2. [Check that you have your Google Calendar public](https://docs.simplecalendar.io/make-google-calendar-public/)
3. [Get your Calendar ID](https://docs.simplecalendar.io/find-google-calendar-id/)
4. Add this file (`fetch.js`) to your `src` file (carefully replacing the variable in the code)

```js
import request from "superagent";
import { Config } from "../../components/Config/Config";

let GOOGLE_CALENDAR_URL = `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${<YOUR_CALENDAR_ID>}/events?key=${<YOUR_API_KEY>}`;

    export function getEvents(callback) {
  request.get(GOOGLE_CALENDAR_URL).end((err, resp) => {
    if (!err) {
      const events = [];
      JSON.parse(resp.text).items.map(event => {
        return events.push({
          start: new Date(event.start.dateTime.toString()),
          end: new Date(event.end.dateTime.toString()),
          title: event.summary
        });
      });
      callback(events);
    }
  });
}
```

5. Finally, in your `App.js`, put this code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import BigCalendar from "react-big-calendar";
import moment from "moment";
import { getEvents } from "./fetch";

import "react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css";
import "./App.css";

const localizer = BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment); // or globalizeLocalizer

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      events: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getEvents(events => {
      this.setState({ events });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BigCalendar
          localizer={localizer}
          events={this.state.events}
          startAccessor="start"
          endAccessor="end"
          defaultView="week"
          culture="fr"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Although I haven't added the interactions in the code, but you can [have a closer look at this page to know more](http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html).

Sources:

- [React Calendar with Google Calendar as CMS — tutorial](https://blog.daftcode.pl/react-calendar-with-google-calendar-as-cms-tutorial-5f5d81e425a9)
- [Big Calendar](http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html)